# Session Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Tenho dois sistemas diferentes. Ambos criados com codeigniter.

**O problema é o seguinte:** Faço *logon* no 1 sistema e utilizo normalmente, então abro o 2 sistema, e então ocorre que o *session* desse novo sistema sobrescreve a do antigo. Então quando eu vou salvar o `id` do usuário guardado na `session` no `db` do primeiro sistema, ele insere o `id` do usuário logado do novo sistema.

Alguma dica ou sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar o

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = "ci_session";
```

ele vem como padrão. então altere para um de sua preferencia que não seja igual o do outro sistema.

**OBS:**

O navegador salva a `session` como `cookie`, então quando os sistemas possui o mesmo nome de `session` ele acaba usando a do que foi iniciado depois.
então quando os nomes são diferentes ele cria outro `cookie` de uma nova `session` ao invés de sobrescrever à antiga.

Comment: Marque a resposta pra não deixar a pergunta aberta...

Answer (score 1):

Isso está relacionado com as [Session Preferences](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session%20domains#session-preferences). Você tem que dizer para a aplicação em que contexto ela deve gerenciar/ler dados da sessão. A documentação diz que as opções de configuração `cookie_domain` e `cookie_path` influenciam no comportamento da sessão, conforme se verifica no *link* indicado acima:

> In addition to the values above, the cookie and native drivers apply the following configuration values shared by the Input and Security classes:

Diga para a biblioteca de sessão qual o domínio ou o *path* para o qual a sessão atual se aplica. Se vc deixar isso em branco na configuração da aplicação (`application/config/config.php`), o *browser* vai entender que a sessão é válida para todos os contextos, e vai usá-la dessa forma.

Pra evitar isso, altere `application/config/config.php` para o domínio correto:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'aplicacao.com.br';
```

Ou para o *path* correto:

```
$config['cookie_path']      = '/aplicacao';
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! mas no meu caso não se resolveu assim. eu dei uma lida na documentação  e vi que basta alterar o $config['sess_cookie_name'] padrão